# using puppet file_line to disable Transparent Huge Pages (THP)

Tags: puppet, centos7, huge-pages

I'm using the below code to disable THP Enabled using puppet

```
file_line { 'disable-THP-enabled':
  ensure => present,
  path   => '/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled',
  line   => 'never',
}
```

But I get the below error message:

```
Error: Could not set 'present' on ensure: Invalid argument - /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled at 43:/home/Sandeep_Kanabar/devops/puppet/modules/profile/manifests/setup_os_params.pp 
Error: Could not set 'present' on ensure: Invalid argument - /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled at 43:/home/Sandeep_Kanabar/devops/puppet/modules/profile/manifests/setup_os_params.pp 
Wrapped exception: 
Invalid argument - /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled 
Error: /Stage[main]/Profile::Setup_os_params/File_line[disable-THP-enabled]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Could not set 'present' on ensure: Invalid argument - /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled at 43:/home/Sandeep_Kanabar/devops/puppet/modules/profile/manifests/setup_os_params.pp
```

This only happens when THP is actually enabled. For e.g

```
# cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
[always] madvise never.
```

If the THP is disabled, then this error doesn't occur. For e.g

```
# cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
always madvise [never]
```

A similar puppet code works when setting swappiness to 0.

```
file_line { 'set-swappiness':
  ensure => present,
  path   => '/proc/sys/vm/swappiness',
  line   => '0',
}
```

Can someone point out what could I be missing or doing wrong? I'm using standalone puppet version 3.8.6. This is a masterless setup on CentOS 7.2

Comment: save yourself the grief, use https://forge.puppet.com/thias/sysctl

Comment: No. it cannot handle transparent huge pages. Or I'm mistaken? I finally solved the issue with the use of simple exec

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is how file_line is working is not compatible how sysfs filesystem is working. For example, you can't really open the said file with text editor and try to write modifications into it but you can write a totally new file that replaces the old content totally.

Maybe this will work:

file { '/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled':
  content      => 'never',
}

or use puppet-sysfs module ..

Comment: Thanks. That's a good and simple solution. I tried the file one and get the below error:

`Error: Could not back up /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled: Got passed new contents for sum {md5}6ee29af1cbd80d64e33233f14d545fa2
Error: /Stage[main]/Profile::Setup_os_params/File[/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled]/content: change from {md5}6ee29af1cbd80d64e33233f14d545fa2 to {md5}c7561db7a418dd39b2201dfe110ab4a4 failed: Could not back up /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled: Got passed new contents for sum {md5}6ee29af1cbd80d64e33233f14d545fa2`

Comment: The sysfs module might not help since the file isn't present in CentOS box. I've been successfully able to apply THP disabled permanently to `/etc/rc.local` using file_line. Just trying to apply to the current kernel.

Answer (score 0):

The idea to use unless in the resource **file** fails indeed. but! it can be implemented with onlyif in exec.

```
exec { 'thp-status':                                                                                                                                                           
  command  => "echo ${thp_status} > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled",                                                                                            
  provider => shell,                                                                                                                                                         
  onlyif   => "egrep -q  '\\[${thp_status}\\]' /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled || echo THP-enabled should be corrected",                                         
}
```

Actually it is possible to do it without onlyif

```
exec { 'thp-status':                                                                                                                                                           
   command  => "egrep -q  '\\[${thp_status}\\]' /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled || echo ${thp_status} > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled",             
   provider => shell,                                                                                                                                                         
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Try this. I hope this should work.